# How to add input fields that will update once values are entered?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I am creating a javascript for creating SVG graphs based on user-input parameters, and I would like to add some input fields that can accept numeric input and string input. Imagine something like:

```
Graph height: [600]
Background Color: [#dfe0ef]
...
```

^ <sup>Imagine that instead of brackets those are text fields on the page.</sup>

I was wondering if I should use a form for this. But I don't need to send any data to a server, so I would like to stick with only js if possible to keep it simple. I do need the SVG graph to update in the browser every time a new value is entered.

All of the examples I've found so far are more complex than what I need, so it has been difficult to use them as references. So hopefully somebody here can explain: How to add input fields that will update the script (and therefor the SVG) once entered?

Thanks

**Update:** I've got a proof-of-concept working with a DIV tag. So now all that's left is to replace the DIV with an SVG and populate it with more parameters.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Please specify a width, a height, and a background color.</p>

<p>Width:</p>
<input 
 id="i_width" 
 type="number" 
 min="1" 
 max="1024" 
 value="200"
 oninput="render()"
>
<br />

<p>Height:</p>
<input 
 id="i_height" 
 type="number" 
 min="1" 
 max="1024" 
 value="100" 
 oninput="render()"
>
<br />

<p>Background Color:</p>
<input
 id="i_bg_color" 
 type="text" 
 value="#bada55" 
 oninput="render()"
>

<p id="text_output"></p>
<br />
<div id="container_output"></div>

<script>
//Gets all variable values from input fields.
//Input IDs are "i_" + "var_name"
function render() {
  var width = document.getElementById("i_width").value;
 var height = document.getElementById("i_height").value;
 var bg_color = document.getElementById("i_bg_color").value;

//text_output
document.getElementById("text_output").innerHTML = "The width is " + width + ", and the height is " + height + ". The background color is " + bg_color + ".";

//container_output
document.getElementById("container_output").innerHTML = `
<div 
 style="
  width:${width}px;
  height:${height}px;
  background-color:${bg_color};
 ">
</div>
`
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Create `<input>` elements. Use `<your_input_element>.value to get the input number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach listeners for the [oninput](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_oninput.asp) event in JavaScript like so:

```
text_field_element.addEventListener('oninput', () => {
    //redraw 
}
```

where `text_field_element` is some `<input>` element.

Without seeing more details about your implementation, I'm not sure what to say about redrawing the actual graphs, though attaching that listener should get your foot in the door.

Comment: The w3schools link you provided about *oninput Event* is what finally helped me to understand. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it:

```js
theHeight.addEventListener("input", () => {
  theRect.setAttributeNS(null, "height", theHeight.value);
});
```

```css
svg{border:1px solid; width:90vh}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 50">
     <rect id="theRect" x="20" y="10" width="60" height="30" fill="skyBlue" />
</svg>

<input id="theHeight" type="number" min="1" max="40" value="30" />
```